# How to match string that contains ^ in regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I tried to make a regular expression using online tool but not succeeded.  Here is the string i need to match:-

> 27R4FF^27R4FF Text until end

- always starts with alphanumeric (case-insensitive)
- then always caret sign ^ (no space before & after)
- then alphanumeric string
- then always one white space
- then string until end.

Here is the regular expression that is not working for me:-

```
((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*))(\^)((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*)).*?((?:[a-z][a-z]+))
```

c# code:-

```
string txt = "784SFS^784SFS Value is here";

var regs = @"((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*))(\^)((?:[a-z][a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*)).*?((?:[a-z][a-z]+))";
Regex r = new Regex(regs, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
Match m = r.Match(txt);
Console.Write(m.Success ? "matched" : "didn't match");
Console.ReadLine();
```

Help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Didn't it match? Did you get an error? Does `.*\^.*` work, since you seem to think it's because of the `^`?

Comment: Is it required to be alphanumeric?  Or can it just be a string of 6 word characters?

Comment: Do you need to fix your regex or need a regex to satisfy specifications?

Comment: What are you questioning exactly? You title emphasize the caret (^) but the question text just ask us to create a simple regex for you. Please read references on Regular Expressions (e. g. http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and try to provide a good question with a minimal example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verbatim  `^[^\W_]+\^[^\W_]+[ ].*$`

```
 ^              # BOS
 [^\W_]+        # Alphanum
 \^             # Caret
 [^\W_]+        # Alphanum
 [ ]            # Space
 .*             # Anything
 $              # EOS
```

Output

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 28 ) 
27R4FF^27R4FF Text until end
```

Comment: I'm not so sure about `[^\W_]`. It contains a double negation: "match character that is not a non-word character". I think it's a complex way to write `\w` (lowercase). But I like the whole break-up of the regex. That is usually very informative to beginners. More [info about character classes can be found on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: @GolezTrol  - What is the problem with double negation? `[^\W_]` _is exactly_ `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. If that's too much then whitespace boundary's will kill you `(?<!\S)(?!\S)`. Again, `\w` and `\W` and '\pL` and `\PL` are character classes that can go inside class construct. These are regex facts to be understood. The sooner, the better.

Comment: This is a common one as well `[^\S\r\n]` says match horizontal whitespace. Get used to this, this is the tools used in regex you have to know how to use..

Comment: It's not a problem per se, but I thought that `[^\W]` is the same as `\w`, so I wondered why you didn't write `\w`.

Comment: @GolezTrol  - The scope of a negated class is throughout the class. This allows you to trim items from predetermined classes. If I wanted alphanum and horizontal whitespace, it would be `[^\W\r\n\S_]` this avoids having to write it all out, but make no mistake, the engine resolves it to exactly the same values as if you wrote it out longhand.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get if string 'until the end' should be matched.

This works for

```
27R4FF^27R4FF Text

^\w+\^\w+\s\w+$
```

if you have some spaces at the end, try with

```
^\w+\^\w+\s[\w\s]+$
```

Comment: \w will match underscore, so this doesn't strictly match the pattern the OP mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://regex101.com/r/hD0hV0/2

```
^[\da-z]+\^[\da-z]+\s.*$
```

...or commented (assumes RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace if you're using the format in code):

```
^          # always starts...
[\da-z]+   # ...with alphanumeric (case-insensitive)
\^         # then always caret sign ^ (no space before & after)
[\da-z]+   # then alphanumeric string
\s         # then always one white space
.*         # then string...
$          # ...until end.
```

The other answers don't actually match what you describe (at the time of this writing) because \w matches underscore and you didn't mention any limitations on "the string at the end".

Comment: So true. Alphanumeric is a clear description, and it makes sense for a code like this to be strictly alphanumeric.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff - Not if he's using RegexOptions.IgnoreCase (which he is in his example code).

Comment: Ahh, missed that in the actual C#!